# How to Zip(s1, o1) where s1 happens only once and o1 happens multiple times?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

Let's say that I need to do when s1 and o1 have completed, but s1 happens only once and o1 happens multiple times, and I need to do something each time o1 happens. How can I do that?

I have tried the following code,

```
val s1 = Single.fromCallable {
    Log.d("so","executing s1");
    "hello";
}.cache();

var emitter:ObservableEmitter<String>? = null;
val o1 = Observable.create<String> {
    emitter = it;
}

Observable.zip(s1.toObservable(),o1,
        BiFunction<String, String, Array<String>>() { t1, t2 -> arrayOf(t1,t2); })
        .subscribe { t1 ->
            Log.d("so", "Result = " + t1.joinToString(","));
        }

emitter?.onNext("homer");
emitter?.onNext("marge");
emitter?.onNext("bart");
Log.d("so", "Done");
```

But the result was

```
executing s1,
Result = hello,homer
Done
```

When the result I expected was

```
executing s1,
Result = hello,homer
Result = hello,marge
Result = hello,bart
Done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
s1.flatMapObservable({ t1 -> o2.map({ t2 -> arrayOf(t1, t2) }) })
```

Also use `PublishSubject` instead of sneaking out the emitter:

```
val o2 = PublishSubject.create();

s1.flatMapObservable({ t1 -> o2.map({ t2 -> arrayOf(t1, t2) }) })
.subscribe { t1 ->
    Log.d("so", "Result = " + t1.joinToString(","));
}

o2.onNext("homer");
o2.onNext("marge");
o2.onNext("bart");

Log.d("so", "Done");
```

Comment: It works. Also, thank you for the PublishSubject tip.